# Getting all ids and usernames from membership Asp Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, membershipuser

I have no doubt on how to retrieve membership id from 1 single user:

```
currentUser = Membership.GetUser(); 
Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
```

but I can´t find a way to retrieve all users id and usernames.

I tried this way:

```
MembershipUserCollection AllUsers;
AllUsers = GetAllUsers();
```

From that point I can´t find a way to retrieve Ids and Usernames from AllUsers.
Could I get some help from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for Membership.GetAllUsers()

```
var users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
foreach (MembershipUser membershipUser in users)
{
    // membershipUser.UserName;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.getallusers.aspx